# Haskell Infinity check for Double data type

Tags: haskell, floating-point

How do you check if a `Double` value is `Infinity` in Haskell?

Comment: [`isInfinite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:isInfinite)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RealFloat` class, of which both `Float` and `Double` are instances, has an [isInfinite](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:isInfinite) method.